# A combinatorial problem about sequences of numbers

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

In [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4668840/111012) Adam Rubinson asked (I paraphrase):

> Given a natural number $r$, what is the least number $n$ such that every strictly increasing sequence of $n$ real numbers has a subsequence $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r$ of length $r$ whose sequence of differences $x_2-x_1,x_3-x_2,\dots,x_r-x_{r-1}$ is (nonstrictly) monotonic? (E.g., if $r=4$ then $n=7$.)

I can't recall having seen this before, but it seems like a reasonably natural question, so it must be discussed somewhere in the literature. Where?

**Edit.** I'm not sure the question should be closed as a duplicate, seeing as I posted it as a reference request, and I still don't know where or whether this result appears as a traditional publication.

I would have expected this to be a "classical" problem. It's hard to believe that it's not among the thousands of problems Paul Erdős wrote about.

Comment: This is an obvious comment, but it of course feels similar to the famous Erdős–Szekeres theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90128/erd%C5%91s-szekeres-for-first-differences . Note that the "increasing" condition does not change anything, since you can always add an arithmetic sequence with sufficiently high difference to your sequence, which will make it increasing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erdős-Szekeres for first differences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90128/erd%c5%91s-szekeres-for-first-differences)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Wow, thanks! Is the only reference a math overflow post?

Comment: Well, the MO post is the first thing that came up on a search for "convex subsequence erdos-szekeres", and the next two hits are a different problem. Maybe something else is hiding further down -- no idea.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks. It's not clear to me that a discussion of this problem will necessarily include the keywords "convex" or "erdos-szekeres"; Adam Rubinson's math.SE question had neither.

Comment: The MO question linked by Darij has a hidden/deleted answer by Gjergji Zaimi which does not solve this problem but indicates that the same answer appears in a similar problem about sequences of points in general position on the plane containing either an "$l$-cap" or a "$k$-cup" (natural notions expressed using slopes computed via differences of coordinates), and that problem is solved in the original paper of Erdős–Szekeres (http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1935__2__463_0). Probably you just have to do a careful search through lemmas and propositions of papers that cite Erdős–Szekeres...

Comment: @darijgrinberg No doubt I'm just being stupid, but I don't see why restricting to increasing sequences does not change anything. If I add an arithmetic sequence, then the new sequence will be convex (concave) iff the original sequence was convex (concave), but it is not so for *subsequences*.

Comment: @bof Oops, you're right!

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Actually that old Erdős–Szekeres paper seems to be the reference I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment by [Vladimir Dotsenko](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1306/vladimir-dotsenko), the problem I asked about was posed and solved in the classical paper by Erdős and Szekeres, A combinatorial problem in geometry, *Compositio Math.* 2 (1935), 463–470 ([pdf](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1935__2__463_0.pdf)); see the discussion beginning with "We solve now a similar problem" on p. 468.

In another comment [Darij Grinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2530/darij-grinberg) pointed out that a generalization to possibly non-monotonic sequences was the subject of a 2012 [math overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90128/erd%C5%91s-szekeres-for-first-differences) by [Seva](https://mathoverflow.net/users/9924/seva) which was answered by [Sergey Norin](https://mathoverflow.net/users/8733/sergey-norin).